# How to access all image library in react native through API using Expo

Tags: react-native

I couldn't find any answer online but I remember using this in the past. My need is to call an API to receive all images from the phone library in array of paths format.

i.e. today I know how to access the library through components such as [imagepicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) but I would love to be able to simply get the results in format of:

```
const images = [
  'file://...',
  'file://...',
  'file://...',
  ...
]
```

So I could design a component picker for myself. Anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

React-native provides [CameraRoll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/cameraroll.html) module. You can get data via it.

```js
CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 1000000 }).then(res => {
 console.log(res, "images data")
})
```